# Scheme transposing matrix

Tags: scheme

I have such code in Scheme:

```
(define transpose2                      ;1
 (lambda (A T)                          ;2
  (if (pair? (car A))                   ;3
   (transpose2                          ;4
    (map cdr A) (cons (map car A) T)    ;5
   )                                    ;6
   (reverse T)                          ;7
  )                                     ;8
 )                                      ;9
)                                       ;10
```

I have trouble understanding line nr 5. How creating a pair in this line eventually leads to transposing given matrix?

```
(define transpose                                ;1 
 (lambda (A)                                     ;2
  (transpose2 A `())                             ;3
 )                                               ;4 
)                                                ;5
```

previous function transpose2 is executed by this function and for example:

```
(display (transpose '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
(display (transpose '((3 2 1) (2 1 1) (3 1 1))))
```

gives results:

```
((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
((3 2 3) (2 1 1) (1 1 1))
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? Line 3 in particular uses a very specific condition, and line 7 does not seem to include the last column... e.g. working by hand it seems like `(transpose2 '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))` works out to be `(1 3 4)`, which is very wrong...

Comment: Yes, that code works. I've edited my code with sample results.

Comment: Ahh I see. For some reason I treated `pair?` literally instead of as the same as `cons?` / `list?`.

Comment: It's not an answer to this question, but you might be interested in the classic `(apply map list matrix)`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parameters here: `A`, your original matrix, and `T`, your accumulator.

On line 3, we check if the first element of `A` is a list, e.g. in the form `'(1)`. If so, then we recurse, reducing `A` by one column with `(map cdr A)` and accumulating the first member of each `A` into `T`. When we finally exhaust our list, we reverse our accumulator and return it.

The code could perhaps be made slightly clearer if the condition on line 3 was replaced with `(not (empty? A))`.

Example trace:

```
   (transpose '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
-> (transpose2 '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)) '())
-> (transpose2 (map cdr A) (cons (map car A) T))
-> (transpose2 '((2) (4) (6)) '((1 3 5)))
-> (transpose2 '(() () ()) '((2 4 6) (1 3 5)))
-> (reverse '((2 4 6) (1 3 5)))
-> '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Comment: I skipped over a lot of steps in the breakdown. If you want, I can go more into depth.

Comment: It's not necessary ;) Thanks for help, now I understand.